# With Core Data, should I use one entity or split into smaller ones?

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

For example, I have attributes for an entity like this:

```
category_id
data
```

I don't have complicated operations. I only access the records separately by `category_id == X`. I am wondering if I should use one entity to store all records or split it into N entities where each one represents one category? Should I just consider and design it just like a SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really appropriate for SO (too broad and opinion-based), but here goes...

Data modeling should generally be independent of the underlying representation.  If different categories are different entities, model them that way.  It sounds to me like this is not the case, and if that's so, leave them as one entity.